# cypher find path without a node type

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say I have the following graph

```
(:A) -> (:B) -> (:C) -> (:D)
  \                ^
   \               |
     -> (:X) -> (:Y)
```

Now from A to D, there are two paths

```
(:A) -> (:B) -> (:C) -> (:D)
```

and

```
(:A) -> (:X) -> (:Y) -> (:C) -> (:D)
```

I can use the query below to return the two path

```
MATCH p1 = ((:A)-[*]-(:Z))
return p1
```

But say I only want to see path that does not contain node type X. What query can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the NONE() predicate function (see https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/predicate/#functions-none)

```
MATCH p1 = ...
WHERE NONE(node IN nodes(p1) WHERE node:X)
```